# Cannot find module '../../images/Logo.png'.ts(2307) Red Error is Still showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, gatsby

I'm using a Gatsby starter to customize a website.

The starter I'm using is this:
https://github.com/fabien0102/gatsby-starter

Why does the following error:

```
Cannot find module '../../images/Logo.png'.ts(2307)
```

continue to show?

Everything seems to load successfully the `logo.png` file in localhost but the path `../../images/logo.png` is still underlined red (which prevents a successful upload to Netlify).

Here's what the `HeaderMenu.tsx` file looks like:

[image: Screenshot of HeaderMenu.tsx]

I'm still learning and your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you reload your VSCode window? Open the command palette (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`) and choose `Reload window`. You probably just need to run the TypeScript compiler again, often this is all it takes :)

Comment: Ok thanks I'll give that a try.

Comment: Naturally, you'll also need to make sure that the image is indeed where you're trying to import it from (in your case, in `/src/images/Logo1.png`). But I'm assuming you've already done this, since this is what the error is saying.

Answer (score 1):

This happens mainly because typescript thinks that there are no type definitions for these imports.

1. Create a `declarations.d.ts` in your `src` folder. IE: `src/declarations.d.ts`.
2. Add declarations for whichever image format you are trying the import. EX:

```
declare module '*.jpg' {
  export default `` as string;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  export default `` as string;
}
```

3. Reload your file aaaaand voilà, you should be in business.